# Hiding/unhiding excel sheets based of a matrix

Tags: excel, vba, loops, hide

I have a macro that works, but it's not very effective and could be done a lot better.

I simply have a list with all sheet names(they could change so it needs to be dynamic) in one row and in the next row I have a "yes/no" answer that displays if the sheet should be hidden or not.

Example:

Sheet 1, sheet2, sheet3, sheet4,

yes, yes, no, yes

My code so far:

```
Sub HidingSheets()

'Checking the first sheet
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sheets(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E9").Value).Visible = True
Sheets(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E9").Value).Activate

If ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "NO" Then
    ActiveSheet.Visible = False
End If
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

'Checking the second sheet
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sheets(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F9").Value).Visible = True
Sheets(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("F9").Value).Activate

If ActiveSheet.Range("A1") = "NO" Then
    ActiveSheet.Visible = False
End If
'-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

End Sub
```

I basically do it manually per every sheet instead of a loop, and this also requires that I need the "yes/no" displayed in every sheet(the "if" formula checking if A1 = "no"). The "yes/no" that s displayed in cell A1 is taken from the matrix that I explained before.

Note: The matrix could be "tranposed", the direction of it doesn't matter.

Thank you in advance if you can help me.

My second attempt is this:

```
Sub Hiding2()

Dim i As interger

For i = 1 To 10

    a = ActiveSheet.Range("E9").Value

    If Offset(a(1, 0)) = YES Then
        Sheets(a).Visible = True
    Else
       Sheets(a).Visible = False
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

But I dont know how to reference the cells that I need, and then get them to move over for every "i".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub HideWorksheets()
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim Data As Range: Set Data = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E9:N9")
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each Cell In Data
        Worksheets(Cell.value).Visible = IIf(Cell.Offset(1, 0) = "YES", xlSheetHidden, xlSheetVisible)
    Next Cell
End Sub
```

Comment: Not "False"! Not "True"! But "xlSheetHidden" (=0) or "xlSheetVeryHidden" (=2) or 
xlSheetVisible (=-1)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Cells` instead of `Range`. With it, you can use column numbers to iterate over some range of columns. There is also other possibilities to exit the code... it depends on the data in your worksheet.

```
Sub Hiding()
    Dim sh as Worksheet, col as Integer
    For col = 5 to 100
        shName = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(9, col).Value
        On Error GoTo TheEnd ' in case there is no such sheet
        Set sh = Worksheets(shName)
        If UCase(sh.Range("A1").Value) = "YES" Then
            sh.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        Else
            sh.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        End If
    Next col
    TheEnd:
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked fine, I preffered the above answer though, because of the way how I specify where the cells are, instead of counting rows and columns I can then only type the cell reference. But thank you anyway!